# How to remove a tag from XML Document using C#?

Tags: c#, xmldocument

```
<sg>
       <userdata>
            <data>
             <tag name="gf" description="fg" nodeid="                                                      {2F2CC6951E2B4EEA979F357164CB73E5}" controllerid="" keytype="" mask="" track="widthsegment"    numkey="" interpolator="" frame="" aindex="1" number="1">
              <![CDATA[  //sg/objects/object[@id="          {2F2CC6951E2B4EEA979F357164CB73E5}"]/params/param[@name="widthsegment"]
               ]]> 
               </tag>
              <tag name="gf" description="fg" nodeid="               {2F2CC6951E2B4EEA979F357164CB73E5}" controllerid="" keytype="" mask="" track="widthsegment"                       numkey="" interpolator="" frame="" aindex="1" number="2">
               <![CDATA[  //sg/objects/object[@id="                         {2F2CC6951E2B4EEA979F357164CB73E5}"]/params/param[@name="widthsegment"]
              ]]> 
              </tag>
                </data>
               </userdata>
                    </sg>
```

I want to remove the " tag " - tag from this how to do this

I made like this

```
updatedData.SelectSingleNode("//tag[@name='" + 1 + "']").RemoveAll();
```

But still tag comes in this .. i mean empty tag .. how to remove that

after that

```
                   <sg>
                    <userdata>
                      <data>
                      <tag /> --- This is wat i want to remove... how to remove this
                       <tag name="gf" description="fg" nodeid="        {2F2CC6951E2B4EEA979F357164CB73E5}" controllerid="" keytype="" mask="" track="widthsegment"      numkey="" interpolator="" frame="" aindex="1" number="2">
                      <![CDATA[  //sg/objects/object[@id="           {2F2CC6951E2B4EEA979F357164CB73E5}"]/params/param[@name="widthsegment"]
                    ]]> 
                     </tag>
                      </data>
```

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)? Where are you stuck? Please post the code you have written so far and explain what is not working.

Comment: it's `C#` not csharp. Correct it. but, it's not reason for downvote and it's not me.

Comment: How have you loaded the `XML string`? In fact. What have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
XmlNodeList nodes = updatedData.GetElementsByTagName("tagname");
foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
{
    if (node.ChildNodes.Count == 0)
        node.RemoveAll();
    else
        UpdateDoc.InnerXml = node.OuterXml;
}
```

I solved this ...

Comment: Where did `UpdateDoc` come from?

Answer (score 1):

```
var xmlDoc = XDocument.Load("filename.xml");
var element = (
    from x in xmlDoc.Root.Elements("elemnt-name")
    where x.Element("tage-name").Value == "xxxx"
    select x
    ).FirstOrDefault();
element.Remove();
xmlDoc .Save("filename.xml");
```

Comment: How can i add this in  "XmlNodeList " if I make XmlNodeList xn = xmldoc; it shows error... how can i add this xmldoc to my "xn"

Comment: why do u want to load it into XmlNodeList ?

Comment: xmlDoc .Save("filename.xml"); I want to load this in XmlNodeList . I dont want to save this and all just want to assign to XmlNodeList ...

Comment: XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"C:\Users\sghaida\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\testing-ws-1\XMLParser\config.xml");
            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            XmlNodeReader nodeReader = (XmlNodeReader)doc.CreateReader();
            xmlDoc.ReadNode(nodeReader);
            XmlNodeList xmlnodeList = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("node");

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19642/discussion-between-user1806245-and-saddam-abu-ghaida)

Answer (score 0):

Your XPath is strange:

```
"//tag[@name='" + 1 + "']"
```

It will select all `tag` elements that have a `name` attribute with the value of 1. There are none in your example.

You are also using `SelectSingleNode` which will only select a single node.

The XPath should be `"//tag"` if you wish to select them all, and you should be using `SelectNodes` instead.

Answer (score 0):

this is how you do the loading for xdocument to XmlNodeList

```
 XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"C:\Users\sghaida\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\testing-ws-1\XMLParser\config.xml");
                XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
                XmlNodeReader nodeReader = (XmlNodeReader)doc.CreateReader();
                xmlDoc.ReadNode(nodeReader);
                XmlNodeList xmlnodeList = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("node");
```